# Fazer um novo framework baseado em outro open source com licença GPL

Tags: licença, código-aberto, gpl

Quero utilizar partes de um *framework open source* disponibilizado no Github sobre uma licença GPL. Vou subir o meu código no Github e também sobre a licença GPL. Ao finalizar o meu *framework*, quero fazer *templates* para ser utilizado junto a ele, mas com **distribuições separadas**, onde os *templates* serão vendidos ou trocados por pontos.

1. Se fizer desta forma estou infrigindo algo da licença GPL?
2. Tenho que de alguma forma dizer que utilizei partes de um outro *framework*?

Hoje o que já faço são comentários nos cabeçalhos das classes ou métodos que foram copiados ou inspirados pelo *framework*/código de terceiros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se houver total separação, se o código do que vai "comercializar" (mesmo que não seja dinheiro mesmo) não conter nada do que está em GPL, nada mesmo, então não há problema. Você consegue garantir isto?

Um software depender de outro GPL não é problema, mas este outro dependente não pode ser distribuído junto com a parte GPL, em hipótese alguma.

E o código GPL que você manipulou não pode depender da parte não GPL.

De qualquer forma, o melhor que eu posso fazer é dizer para consultar um advogado especializado se realmente não quer se meter em encrenca. Não confie em pessoas aleatórias na internet te dando conselho jurídico.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, inicialmente não irei consultar um advogado pq por enquanto a ideia é ser tudo opensource, mas caso os templates eu venha a comercializar, irei seguir o seu conselho e procurar um especialista.

Comment: Eu ia dizer praticamente a mesma coisa, inclusive a parte de procurar um advogado especializado. ;)  +1

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo o que é descrito [aqui](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License):

> Em termos gerais, a GPL baseia-se em 4 liberdades:
>
> A liberdade de executar o programa, para qualquer propósito (liberdade
>   nº 0) 
> A liberdade de estudar como o programa funciona e adaptá-lo para
>   as suas necessidades (liberdade nº 1). O acesso ao código-fonte é um
>   pré-requisito para esta liberdade.
>  A liberdade de redistribuir cópias
>   de modo que você possa ajudar ao seu próximo (liberdade nº 2).
>  A
>   liberdade de aperfeiçoar o programa, e liberar os seus
>   aperfeiçoamentos, de modo que toda a comunidade se beneficie deles
>   (liberdade nº 3). O acesso ao código-fonte é um pré-requisito para
>   esta liberdade.

Tudo que for gerado a partir de um software livre, também deve ser livre. 
Complementando a resposta com mais uma citação do link onde diz:

> A licença não permite, por exemplo, que o código seja apoderado por
>   outra pessoa, ou que sejam impostos sobre ele restrições que impeçam
>   que seja distribuído da mesma maneira que foi adquirido.